# Gson-like library for scala

Tags: java, json, scala, playframework-2.5

I'm learning scala. I'm trying to find an easy way for turing JSON String to Scala case class instance. Java has wonderful library called Google Gson. It can turn java bean to json and back without some special coding, basically you can do it in a single line of code.

```
public class Example{
  private String firstField
  private Integer secondIntField

  //constructor

  //getters/setters here
}
//Bean instance to Json string
String exampleAsJson = new Gson().toJson(new Example("hehe", 42))

//String to Bean instance
Example exampleFromJson = new Gson().fromJson(exampleAsJson, Example.class)
```

I'm reading about https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJson and can't get the idea: why it's so complex is scala? Why should I write readers/writers to serialize/deserialize plain simple case class instances? Is there easy way to convert case class instance -> json -> case class instance using play json api?

Comment: jackson has a `DefaultScalaModule` that works pretty well for all the standard collections and case classes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have

```
case class Foo(a: String, b: String)
```

You can easily write a [formatter](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#format) for this in Play by doing

```
implicit val fooFormat = Json.format[Foo]
```

This will allow you to both serialize and deserialize to JSON.

```
val foo = Foo("1","2")
val js = Json.toJson(foo)(fooFormat)  // Only include the specific format if it's not in scope.
val fooBack = js.as[Foo]              // Now you have foo back!
```

Comment: Gson will convert any case class to Json in generic code. The above requires you to write a formatter for each of your case classes (for instance, I have 124 models), and will not work for generic code that doesn't know if there is a 125th. Long live Gson. Just add `libraryDependencies += "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.8.0"` to build.sbt.

Comment: If you're using Play framework, the code will not compile if you are attempting to send a `JsValue` in a controller that does not have a `writes` instance defined for it. GSON is all runtime and also does not know about native Scala types (`Option`, `scala.collection.immutable.Map`, etc) which will require you to hand write serializers for these.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [uPickle](http://www.lihaoyi.com/upickle-pprint/upickle/)

Here's a small example:

```
case class Example(firstField: String, secondIntField: Int)

val ex = Example("Hello", 3)

write(ex) // { "firstField": "Hello", "secondIntField" : 3 }
```